# R markdown file (knitr) stops working after R and Rstudio Update

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

R markdown file (previously) (knitr) stops working after R (to 3.2.0) and Rstudio (to 0.99.441) Update (had to reinstall all packages)

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(lumvalsstd1on.data[2:12], digits = 2,
             caption = "Data Analysis of standards from lights on measurement")
```
````

When i try to convert it to a pdf using knitr I get the error:

```
Quitting from lines 66-67 (Rcourse15_report_expt1.Rmd) 
Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'lumvalsstd1on.data' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> <Anonymous> -> colnames -> is.data.frame
Execution halted
```

Tried the solution given [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202705076-R-Markdown-File-Not-Knitting-Since-Recent-RStudio-Update) but it does not seem to work, but still am searching for a solution.
I think I have all the required packages. It some how doesn't seem to find the data frames produced from R script.

Comment: It sounds like `lumvalsstl1on.data` isn't imported into the new R session created by knitr. Do you call `load(something.rda)` (wherever you have the object saved) earlier in the .Rmd file?

Comment: No, I just run the R script to modify the data frame with new values and it gets saved in the Global Environment. Then I directly use knitr::kable to print it as a table on markdown (it worked well before).